# write addtional data to excel after creating it with dataframe

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, pandas.excelwriter

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame(Numpy_Array1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(Numpy_Array2)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Results.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'Array1')
df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'Array2')
writer.save()
```

Hello I have written some dataframes to excel with ExcelWriter and now I want to add following things to each sheet directly below the last row of each sheet (leaving one row free in between):

```
a=10
b=20
c=40
d=80
```

how do I do that ?

Comment: Why don't you try first, and then show us what you tried and if it failed.

Comment: @Chris I looked around in internet but didn't found any helpful sites and I am running out of time so I posted here.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it:

```
import pandas as pd

Numpy_Array1 = [10, 20, 30, 20, 15]
Numpy_Array2 = [10, 20, 30, 20, 15, 30, 45]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(Numpy_Array1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(Numpy_Array2)

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Results.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'Array1')
df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'Array2')


workbook = writer.book

worksheet = writer.sheets['Array1']
last_row = len(Numpy_Array1) + 2  # Allow for header row and padding.
col = 0
worksheet.write(last_row + 0, col, 'a')
worksheet.write(last_row + 1, col, 'b')
worksheet.write(last_row + 2, col, 'c')
worksheet.write(last_row + 3, col, 'd')

col = 1
worksheet.write(last_row + 0, col, 10)
worksheet.write(last_row + 1, col, 20)
worksheet.write(last_row + 2, col, 40)
worksheet.write(last_row + 3, col, 80)

# Repeat for Numpy_Array2 or add a loop.

writer.save()
```

**Output:**

[image]

The key to the solution is getting a handle to the underlying workbook and from there the worksheet. See the [Working with Pandas chapter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html) of the XlsxWriter docs for more information.

Comment: Thanks, how would you do if a,b,c and d should be in the first column and 10,20,40 and 80 in the second ?